# How to use forecast.time.day?

Tags: api, openweathermap

I am using the openweathermap api https://openweathermap.org/forecast16
And there is such a function forecast.time.day
Question: How do I use it?
I did not find an example on the site and I do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API documentation](https://openweathermap.org/forecast16) forecast.time.day isn't a function but a parameter of the api call result.

Comment: an I get a forecast for a specific day? I just did not quite understand the documentation. I need to get a forecast for a specific day, but I do not know which request to send (

Comment: You can request a forecast from today up to 16 days, limited by the `cnt` parameter. Pick any of the example and look the result for the `list` object, you'll find a `dt` for each item: that's an epoch timestamp representing the day of the forecast